# Invoking Native Code with Java ME

Tags: java, java-native-interface

From what I read, Java Native Interface is not supported by the Java ME platform. What are some other possible way for Java ME applications to reuse existing native libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how feasable this is on mobile platforms but I would wrap a native executable around the C/C++ libraries and let the executable expose a lightweight RPC protocol based on something like Hessian or JSON-rpc or perhaps a basic HTTP and rest.

This comparision of lightweight web servers might get you started if you want to go the HTTP+REST route

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_lightweight_web_servers

Comment: This could work well.  We run a Java system with a full-blown self contained HTTP server and app engine using a brower for the UI on handheld computers.